# Join on clustered tables shows greater cost than non-clustered tables?

Tags: sql, oracle, oracle10g

I have created a cluster and a two tables `emp` and `sep` on the cluster.

Now when I do the simple query...

```
explain plan select * from emp_cluster join dep_cluster using (dno)
```

...the cost is 26.

I created two other tables on heap (`emp_heap` and `dep_heap`) and the when I do...

```
explain plan select * from emp_heap join dep_heap using (dno)
```

...the cost is only 15.

Which is less than that of cluster. I have inserted 33000 records in the emp tables and 99 records in the department tables. I know that in join cluster behaves good but in my case it is opposite...?

Comment: MySQL _and_ Oracle? What are the indexes also? And [select * is considered harmful](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3639861/why-is-select-considered-harmful).

Comment: @Ben I have put index on the cluster too

Comment: There might be better answers for this found on the DBA stack exchange site. Unfortunately we can't migrate it from here.

Comment: There are several options for CLUSTERs, you may want to post all the DDL and some sample data.

Answer (score 4):

Possible causes:

- Statistics out of date
- The clustered tables are fragmented or have low fill factor

Please post the two plans.